# Add new row to table on click and populate new black row

Tags: angular, typescript, html-table, dynamic-tables

I have table where I am showing Article Number and Description of werbedata. I want to add new article and description after all the data populaed in table and when i click on add, that row should stay as it is and new blank row should get added below it. Now, I am able to add new row but it is disappearing and only blank fields are generating again.Below is my code:

HTML :

```
<md-card class="default-card">
  <h1>{{ 'Edit Details' }}</h1>
</md-card>

<div class="flex">
  <md-card class="werbedata-details">
    <div *ngIf="werbedata">
      <md-input-container>
        <input mdInput placeholder="{{ 'Werbe Nummer' }}" [(ngModel)]="werbedata.WERBE_NR" name="WERBENR" disabled type="text">
      </md-input-container>
      <md-input-container>
        <input mdInput placeholder="{{ 'Produkt Name (Werbe Name)' }}" [(ngModel)]="werbedata.Produktbez" name="Produkt Name">
      </md-input-container>
      <md-input-container>
        <input mdInput placeholder="{{ 'Werbetext' }}" [(ngModel)]="werbedata.Werbetext" name="Werbetext">
      </md-input-container>
      <md-input-container>
        <input mdInput placeholder="{{ 'Produkt Bezeichnung' }}" [(ngModel)]="werbedata.Produktbez" name="Bezeichnung">
      </md-input-container>
      <md-input-container>
        <input mdInput placeholder="{{ 'VK-Einheit' }}" [(ngModel)]="werbedata.MGEHT" name="MGEHT">
      </md-input-container>
    </div>
  </md-card>
  <md-card class="werbenumber-list">
    <md-card-content>
      <table>
        <thead>
          <th> Artikle </th>
          <th> Description </th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let product of this.products">
            <td>{{ product.ARTNR }}</td>
            <td>{{ product.PRODUKTBEZ }}</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="newValuesARTNR" [(ngModel)]="newValues.ARTNR" name="newValuesARTNR" />
            </td>
            <!-- <td>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="newAttributeName" [(ngModel)]="newAttribute.PRODUKTBEZ" name="newAttributePRODUKTBEZ" />
            </td> -->
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" (click)="addFieldValue(newValues.ARTNR)">Add</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </md-card-content>
  </md-card>
  <div class="endbuttons" align="end">
    <button md-raised-button (click)="goBack()">
      {{ 'cancel' }}
      <md-icon>cancel</md-icon>
    </button>
    <button md-raised-button color="primary" (click)="editWerbedata(werbedata)">
      {{ 'save' }}
      <md-icon>save</md-icon>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

EditDetailsPage.ts

```
  getWerbeData(filialewerbenr) {
    this.werbedataService.getWerbeData(filialewerbenr)
      .then(
        werbedata => {
          this.werbedata = werbedata[0];
          let artns = this.werbedata.ArtNr.split(' ');
          this.anums = artns;
          for (let a of artns) {
            this.getProduktData(this.werbedata.FILIALE + a);
          }
        },
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
      );
  }

  getProduktData(artnr) {
    this.produktService.getProdukt(artnr)
      .then(
        (produkt: Produkt) => {
          produkt[0] = this.InitiateImagesUrls(produkt[0]);
          this.produkt = produkt[0];
          if (this.products.indexOf(this.produkt) === -1) {
            this.products.push(this.produkt);
          }
          this.urls.push(this.produkt.PfadBild_1);
        },
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error,
    );
  }

  addFieldValue(artnr) {
    this.werbedata.ArtNr = this.werbedata.ArtNr + ' ' + artnr;
    console.log('new values', this.werbedata.ArtNr);
    this.newValues = {};
}

  editWerbedata(werbedata) {
    this.werbedataService.updateWerbedata(this.werbedata)
      .then(
        response => {
          console.log('edit function', response);
        }
      );
  }
```

What I am trying to do here is, editing all the details of Werbedata. I am understanding how should I add newly added rows with new article and description to my "update werbedata" method.

MyJsonObject :

---

```
0:
Aktiv_Log:""
Aktiv_Log_leer:""
ArtNr:"3323 3319 3322 3331 3309 3317 3316 3329 3330 3332 3324"
ArtNr_01:"3323"
ArtNr_01_Name:"Schoko-Krokant 2 kg"
ArtNr_01_PRZ:""
ArtNr_01_S:"H3323"
ArtNr_02:"3319"
ArtNr_02_Name:"Schoko 2 kg"
ArtNr_02_PRZ:""
ArtNr_02_S:"H3319"
```

### and so on...

Can anyone please tell me how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

what you have to do is take the value from the form and add it to the `products` array after creating a `product` object.

I created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/test-app-for-table) to demostrate that. take a look.

Comment: @Thanks Anuradha...i did not understand this properly..Werbedata has may products like ArtNr in JSON..I want to add my new product's article no in ArtNr filed...Problem is i am able to add new value to that but i am not able to show that value after adding that and then If i want to update my werbedata with newly added value, it is not working...

Comment: Can you explain more about your requirement

Comment: I have werbedata which has many products.. ArtNr are the ids of each product..i am showing these products in table with their description..i want to add new article no and description of product which should be added in "ArtNr" (check MyJsonObject)..and then i hhave to update my werbedata with this newly added value...

Comment: @Anuradha...My update method is working properly...hthe only problem i am facing is, i am not understanding how to pass newly added values from table to werbedata method...:-(

Comment: still not clear about your requirement. Can you create a stackblitz for that. Then it'll be easy to figure out the issue.

Comment: @Anuradha...https://test-app-for-table.stackblitz.io...I am creating stackblitz for thr first time...dont know how it works...

Comment: If you have created the application successfully. You have to share it. for that there is a share button at the top. click that and copy the first link. And add it here

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173547/discussion-between-anuradha-gunasekara-and-ruchir-naphade).